# CameraX API - How to use it to fixate camera hardware parameter? Or how can I integrate it with Camera2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

**Background and Problem**

I am a researcher and new to android developing, and I am currently doing simple proof-of-concept work by writing an app to capture 9 selfies under different 9 screen illuminations.

I have encountered a problem when I want to fixate as many hardware parameters as possible to make sure there will be no auto-changes in my camera settings when in between 2 selfies. Otherwise, it won't be a valid dataset for my use case.

I built my app and modified on top of `CameraX` (in particular, google's Getting Started with CameraXhttps://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#1 )

I have already researched `Camera2` as an API and its `CaptureRequest` has the functionality to fixate some particular ImageMetadata, such as to disable Auto Exposure, to disable Auto Focus, to disable Auto White Balance, and to fixate Lens Aperature.

**My question is that**

- How to use only cameraX to fixate camera hardware parameter? I did not find the counterpart in cameraX..
- Or how can I integrate cameraX with Camera2 to fixate those things above?
- Or any other "quick and dirty" method than can achieve the purpose I intended?

I thought I can use my Camera2 together with CameraX code because CameraX uses Camera2 API under the hood, but when I tried, the app keeps quitting when running.

Any suggestion will be helpful, Thanks a lot!!!

**Here is my `MainActivity.kt`**

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null 
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File 
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }
        ....
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        ...
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
       // TRY TO FIXATE THE CAMERA PARAMETER HERE
       lateinit var captureBuilder: CaptureRequest.Builder
       captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, 65538)

       val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

       cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    ...
}
```

Can you particularly look at `startCamera()?`, in which I try to fixate the camera setting at beginning?

Comment: Hey, can you edit the code snippet to only include relevent code? Stuff like imports just wastes space.

Comment: Yes, I did. I think can you particularly look at `startCamera()`?, in which I try to fixate the camera setting at beginning?